# Find the process that initiates connection on uDP port 53

Tags: dns, port, monitoring

I am using a windows 7 computer. There is "something" that tries to connect to google DNS via UDP port 53,and this is blocked on a firewall. I want to know which program is doing it,how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

for windows you can use the following command
netstat -ano | find "53"